# Toggling popover(); using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How to toggle popover of the same element? im using ajax so im using `this` to refer to its specific identity, when ajax `success` it will toggle its own popover i took this code from w3schools and use it in mine.

HTML

```
<input type = "text" id = "input_name" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#input_name', function(){
    var myname = $(this).val();

    if(myname != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"sample.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{myname:myname},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(); 
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to call its own popover.

Comment: So the input itself present in the popover?

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/ws5zojyc/3/

see above link it might help you

```
$(function() {
    $("#input_name").popover({
        content: "Enter a text here"
    });
});

$("#input_name").keyup(function(event) {
    var myname = $(this).val();
    // alert(myname);
    if (myname != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/js/?js=" + myname,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                myname: myname
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#input_name').data('bs.popover').tip().find(".popover-content").html(data)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

you can use effect like hover , click etc.